# How to preview all added items in Default GroupedItemsPage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have added 16 items(single group) by simply editing the default grid application. when I run that app, in GroupedItemsPage I can only view 12 out of 16 items but in GroupDetailPage all added items are visible to me. I want to make all the items visible in GroupedItemsPage as well.. Anyone please help me to sort out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GroupedItemsPage just change the `ItemPath` of groupedItemsViewSource CollectionViewSource to `Items` (instead of TopItems). The reason your are seeing only the first twelve is that TopItems is filtered only to the first twelve (the filter is done inside SampleDataGroup)